# Transformless power supply without ground

Tags: power-supply, converter

I would like to make a transformerless power supply, I found some description on the Internet like this [pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00954A.pdf) provided by Microchip. My question is it is possible to use only the phase line(without neutral line) to build a transformerless power supply and power up a microcontroller, for example in the wall mounted light switch I have only the phase.

[This is what I found on the Internet](http://www.aliexpress.com/product-fm/465902149-Wholesale-1-Gang-500M-Distance-315MHz-Wireless-Remote-Control-Touch-Wall-Switch-Light-Lamp-Power-Switch-wholesalers.html), there is only two wire.

### EDITED

---

I just order one of this bulb dimmer, here is a few picture:

[image]

And inside the cover:

[image]
[image]

It seams that there aren't a battery, how is it possible that this circuit is working?

Comment: Did anyone notice "Mechanical life: 5 years"? What a load of crap.

Comment: Yes I saw that, funny :)

Comment: Probably has a built-in PIC10F200 as a timer to signal it when it should fall apart. Can also be a 555 :)

Comment: @Federico: Don't laugh, that's more real than you think.  I once did a product that was rated for one month.  The PIC 10F202 in it deliberately made the product die after 35 days so it wouldn't compete with the longer life products the company was selling, even though the battery would have run it for 3-6 months.

Comment: Olin - There was a recent discussion about printer ink cartridges' life on the local radio. People thought the bastards do the same thing. It appears that the printer stops working to have the piece of foam replaced, which cleans the print head after each use. The repair shop replaces the foam and resets the counter. That's 10 dollar please.

Comment: @Olin - must be great for your conscience, working for such a company! :-/

Comment: @OlinLathrop wow, that is disgusting! stevenh: same as the laptop batteries as I've heard..

Comment: @stevenvh: well, of course. It's the printer business model: make the printer extremely inexpensive, then charge out the wazoo for the ink. A typical inkjet cart holds very little ink (~40mL). Not to mention most modern carts (and even the toner for my Samsung laser printer) have counter circuits in them that count how many pages have been printed, and after a certain threshold, "invalidate" the cart, telling the printer it's empty. So even if you refill it with new ink, it will still display as empty.

Comment: @Shamtam - I have a Canon i865, which I bought because the cartridge is just the ink, not half the printer like in HP and such. Three separate (! another plus) cartridges cost me 20 euro. I find that reasonable. [this is getting way off-topic]

Comment: @stevenvh: No, I don't see anything wrong with this particular case. The customers got everything they were promised, plus a little for margin. This was meant to be a disposable product for use in hospitals. It was completely sealed with one CR2032 battery inside. The company made another product that had two replacable CR2032 batteries that would run for 12-18 months on one set. Not having to deal with low battery simplified the product, since there was always enough battery by the time it quit.

Comment: @stevenvh - "mechanical life 5 years" is a useful spec IF it's real. It's saying that you can reasonably expect it to last 5 years in normal use. Not quite a warranty but not quite a turn their back and walk awaay when sold attitude. Whether it means anything is TBD :-). || Manufacturers rate camera shutters on activations. A minimum is about 50k and a top one is say 300k. A signficant proprotion across the range fail well short and a large % also go on for 500k +. I havge had 200k+ probably from several which made no great claims to longevity.

Comment: @stevenvh: There's nothing wrong such such designs *if* buyer and seller both agree that the customer is effectively paying to rent the product for a month, and will have no property interest in it after that time aside from any possible scrap value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need them both, otherwise you have no voltage difference and no power. You may have to pull wires from a wall outlet instead of the switch. The wall outlet has both phase and neutral.

**edit**
I had a look at the product you refer to in your edit, and you probably mean this:

[image]

I'm not sure, but my guess is that it parasites on the load by placing a small load in series which gives it enough voltage drop to power it. But that would mean it has to switch a load on from time to time to keep going.
In any case, if the \$In\$ comes from a switch, and the \$Out1\$ goes to the neutral, the only thing to make it work is a battery.

Comment: I thought, I edited my question, in the last link there is only two wire, both are phase.

Comment: After some research I found the following site:http://electroschematics.com/6604/touch-light-dimmer-circuit/ It seams that there is only the phase line.

Comment: @Kicsi - That one uses the voltage drop across the triac for its power supply. It's a dimmer, and so has no function if you switch the light off. It couldn't because it wouldn't have power. The Chinese junk seems to suggest it does switch power, and it can switch it off, but how will it switch it on again if there's no two different voltages?

Comment: I just bough one of this switch, you can find some picture above.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot break the rules of Physics.

IF it has Phase and load in only, as shown, and IF it operates a wireless  receiver when it is off, to allow it to be turned on remotely, then it MUST receive energy from somewhere to operate. Available choices are as below - ij the order of decreasing probablility, although the first two are about equal.

- Line power using trickle current through load with operation from small voltage drop when on.
- Internal (supercap or battery) - charged by small drop when on.
- External (eg signal from wireless sender, energy harvesting from heat or vibration etc)

The first is potentially dangerous and will be illegal in some countries.

The second is doable but "has issues" [tm] if left off for long enough.

The third is "nice" but unlikely. Note however that most RFID systems work as per this method. If a receiver can obtain enough energy to identify a turn-on signal it can then use operating voltage drop to operate. So, possible but unlikely.

Answer (score -2):

These circuits fets only for incandescents lamps because they use the return wire as the neutral. Incandescent lamp has low resistence but require lot of current to turn on.
So, if the circuit current consumption is too low compared to incandescent lamp, you can supply power to the circuit but not turns on the lamp.

Explaning based on circuit:

[image]

Once **SW1** (original wall switch) has been removed and replaced by the proposed circuit, as in circuit above, according to the low resistence incandescent lamp properties, the circuit "sees" the return wire as a Neutral (original one, no extra wire). Allowing to supply power necessary to the circuit (around 200mA), without turning the lamp (**L1**) on. By this way, you may have your circuit powered up and control of lamp state.

Comment: -1.  It fails to address any of the issues in the question.

Comment: Maybe I didn´t explained properly. I edited the comment adding an image that explain what I pointed.